# How to fix minijack CTIA OMTP detection?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, manjaro

I have Dell 7540 with Realtek ALC289 sound card and running Manjaro. I'm struggling with my minijack headset with CTIA TRRS plug.

Laptop usually assumes that it's OMTP rendering it useless. Sometimes (around 1 in 5-10 connections) it detects CTIA and works fine. Unfortunately even then sometimes after some time (usually 15-30 minutes) it switches back to OMTP.

How to fix automatic CTIA/OMTP detection? Can I disable it and manually force CTIA?

`alsa-info.sh` output: http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=0c6bbf7d4392edf19debae9daf7497529a30edd6 It's the same no matter if CTIA or OMTP is being outputted.

Comment: answered on https://forum.manjaro.org/t/minijack-ctia-omtp-detection-issue/122204

Comment: Asked by me and not answered at all, but thanks :D